Mathematical notation to cap value on 1?
I have a function $f(x)$, but I want to express the value of $f(x)$ is cap on 1.
In other words, $f(x) = f(x)$, if $f(x)\leq 1$; $f(x)=1$, if $f(x)>1$.
Is there any elegant and concise mathematical notation to express this? Something like $|f(x)|$?
Thanks!

Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, e.g., basic help on mathjax notation, mathjax tutorial and quick reference, main meta site math tutorial and equation editing how-to.

$\min{f(x),1}$

I want to avoid to use min{(),1}, since the definition of () already include min{.}.

Why should whether you've used $\min$ in $f(x)$ affect whether you use $f(x)$ in $\min$? It's not as though it's circular, is it? At any rate, the function you want is $\min{f(x), 1}$, whatever name or expression you give it. Giving it a different expression won't make it not $\min$.

If you want to avoid to use $\min$ directly (I don't know why but ok), you can use $\frac{f(x)+1-|f(x)-1|}{2}$ instead.  This works since $\min(a,b)=\frac{a+b-|a-b|}{2}$.

If your concern is clutter/confusion, just say “$g(x)=\min(f(x),1)$, where $f(x)=$ (some  expression involving mins).”

This is also typical notation: $f(x)\wedge1$

Taking the ideas of @spaceisdarkgreen. Yes, there's a concise and elegant way to express it using the $\min$ function. You can write it as:
$$h(x) = \min(f(x), 1)$$
This notation captures the behavior you are describing. Essentially it means that if $f(x) \leq 1$, the value is still $f(x)$, and if $f(x) > 1$, the value is constrained to $1$.
This approach is simple, readable and widely used in mathematical notation.

Might be better to write it as $g(x) = \min(f(x), 1)$ to make it clear that the capped function is a new function different from $f$.
